# Why don't these range based for loops work properly?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

The output is 2 3 4 5 2293456
              6 10 1355995651 12980632 0

it seems i is not incrementing properly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    vector<int> vec = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    for(int i : x) {
        cout<<x[i]<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl;

    for(int i : vec) {
        cout<<vec[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use range-based for loops, you're getting the *values* in the container, not the indices in the container. So `i` is a value from inside the array/vector, not the index.

Remember: range-based for loops work on containers that don't have indices, like `std::list`, `std::map`, and so forth. They work on arbitrary iterator ranges of values.